# exclude specific folders from dir list

Tags: php

How can I exclude listing of the folders . and .. and other folders like for example the folder 'thumbs 2' from this code.

```
<?php
//Open directory
$dir = dir("../albums/album2/");

//List files in directory
while (($file = $dir->read()) !== false){
        echo " <center><label class='tablog3a'><img src='../albums/album2/thumbs2/$file'> $file<div style='float: right;'> <a href='album2remove.php?file=".$file."'><img src='images/deletetodo.png' class='clickreverse'></a></div></label></center> ";

}

$dir->close();
?>
```

Comment: IMHO, the easiest of the file listing functions is and always has been [glob](http://www.php.net/glob). `glob('../albums/album2/*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);` lists all files with the extension `jpg`, `png` or `gif`. Because it uses pattern matching, you could search for specific files easier that most other methods.

Comment: Do you want to exclude *all* folders or just a few specific ones?

Comment: Is it really any sub folder of the selected path you want to ignore? Then Jacob's solution is simple and very usefull.

Answer (score 3):

in your loop you can do

```
if (!is_dir($file)) {
   //do your echo 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using an if statement in the while loop placed before echo?

```
if ( strcmp($file, "thumbs 2") == 0) {
  continue;
}
```

This also works for "." and ".."

```
if ( strcmp($file, ".") == 0) {
  continue;
}
```

Please note that "strcmp" is an exact match. You might replace it with something like "strpos" or similar which allows sub string match.

Comment: Just an FYI for OP, this is how it would typically be done. You would match the filename against a list that you want to exclude and skip that iteration.

Comment: who said it was wrong? I said `this is how it would typically be done`

Comment: @jonathan I obviously misunderstood your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

hi I hope my code will help you :

```
   $chemin_images = "../albums/album2/";


            // begin view pictures: 
            // ======================
            //echo '<hr>';
            $ext_list = Array("jpg", "jpeg", "bmp", "gif", "png", "tif"); // extensions of picture          
            $listephotos = Array();
            if(file_exists($chemin_images)){
                $dossier = opendir($chemin_images); // open the current folder    
                for($i=0; ($f = readdir($dossier)); $i++){
                    //echo '>';
                    //print_r($f);
                    if($f != "." && $f != ".."){ // is a file                       
                    //echo preg_replace("#(.+)\.(.+)#", "$2", strtolower($f)).'<br>';
                        if(in_array(preg_replace("#(.+)\.(.+)#", "$2", strtolower($f)), $ext_list)){ // if a picture
                            $listephotos[$i] = $f; // add picture
                        }
                    }
                }
                //print_r($listephotos);
                closedir($dossier); // we don't need this folder anymore
                sort($listephotos); // sort by name
                // and now, the view
                $nb_img=1;
                foreach($listephotos as $nom){
                    echo '<div style="width:120px;height:120px; padding:3px;margin:10px;float:left;border:solid black 1px;">';
                        echo '<img src="'.$chemin_images. utf8_encode($nom).'" style="width:100%;height:100%;"/>'; // picture name                  
                    echo '</div>';
                        if($nb_img++==6){ // this part if we want to limit the number of pictures
                            //echo ' ... ';
                            //break;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also try reverse (using [glob](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)), show only files whose extensions given in `{ }`:

```
// Show only php and txt files
foreach (glob("*.{php,txt}", GLOB_BRACE) as $filename) {
    echo $filename . '<br />';
}
```